# Remove <p> when it contains specific string

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

so I try to delete some p html when they elements have this : pasdefichier on.

I try with this code but it doesn't work ! 
I precise the p have been add with ajax. 
how can I do ?

```
$('.downloadfileexintegradedindb').removeByContent('pasdefichier');​
$('.downloadfileexintegradedindb:contains("pasdefichier")').hide();  //to hide
$('.downloadfileexintegradedindb:contains').find('p:contains("pasdefichier")').remove();
```

html code:

```
<p class="downloadfileexintegradedindb" id="123456789" style="position: absolute; top: 36px; left: 123px;">pasdefichier</p>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Snippets below are what you want to achieve.
I used these functions to make it work:

- `.html()` to get the content of the element,
- `.includes()` to check for a string inside this content.

Note that I prefer this method versus `$('p:contains(text)')` because we can easily add a `else` using it.

As you're using jQuery, I used it in my snippets too.
You can of course use `.hide()` instead of `.remove()` if it better fits your needs.

1. If you only have one element:

```js
if ($('#123456789').html().includes('pasdefichier')) {
  console.log('Removed p!');
  $('#123456789').remove();
} else {
  // Do something else
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p class="downloadfileexintegradedindb" id="123456789" style="position: absolute; top: 36px; left: 123px;">pasdefichier</p>
```

2. If you have multiple elements:

```js
$('.p-class').each(function(){
  if($(this).html().includes('pasdefichier')){
    $(this).remove();
  } else {
    // Do something else
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p class="p-class">pasdefichier</p>
<p class="p-class">fichier!</p>
<p class="p-class">fichier!</p>
<p class="p-class">pasdefichier</p>
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Simpler to just use jQuery `contains`

Comment: Merci, cela fonctionne aléatoirement. C'est bien d'avoir des francophones sur stack !

Comment: @mataka Que veux-tu dire par *fonctionne aléatoirement* ? / What do you mean by *randomly working*? Please avoid french, everybody must understand!

Answer (score 3):

Your first line has in it a hidden character (see https://www.soscisurvey.de/tools/view-chars.php), which is at present giving you a `SyntaxError`. When I remove that, I  get a `TypeError` because `removeByContent` is `undefined` (perhaps it is your addition).
But you can just use the second line to achieve what you want (substituting `remove` for `hide`):

```js
$('.downloadfileexintegradedindb:contains("pasdefichier")').remove();  //to hide
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p class="downloadfileexintegradedindb" id="123456789" style="position: absolute; top: 36px; left: 123px;">pasdefichier</p>
```

Answer (score 3):

from the code you posted, lines 2 and 3 are almost correct.

The correct syntax is: `$(':contains(text)')`.
see [JQuery-contains](https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/sel_contains.asp).

So there are two options, depending on what you want to do.
I included both.

```js
$('.downloadfileexintegradedindb').find('p:contains(pasdefichier)').remove(); // if you want to remove only p

$('.downloadfileexintegradedindb:contains(pasdefichier)').remove(); // if you want to remove the whole container
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="downloadfileexintegradedindb">
  <p>123</p>
  <p>pasdefichier</p>
</div>

<div class="downloadfileexintegradedindb">
  <p>123</p>
  <p>abc</p>
</div>
```

Comment: But you have inner quotes too (which is the reason for the downvote, explain it to me and I will gladly remove the downvote) ?

Comment: @doubleOrt yes a lot

Comment: @doubleOrt ok you are right it works with quotes too.

Comment: @doubleOrt API docs suggests using quotes. Not a good reason to down vote when it follows documentation http://api.jquery.com/contains-selector/

Comment: @charlietfl I actually downvoted because you had quotes in your example too. Now that it doesn't, I should remove my downvote.

Comment: @doubleOrt what is wrong with using quotes? Did you read the docs?

Comment: @charlietfl Well, your answer implied that using quotes was wrong and at the same time you used them in your example, so I was confused.

Comment: @doubleOrt I never answered the question. Was simply commenting that using quotes is fine as per `text inside the parentheses of :contains() can be written as a bare word or surrounded by quotation marks`

Comment: Its the same thing. I forgot to remove the quotes in my example, thats all.

Comment: @charlietfl Sorry, thought you were OP. I don't think anything is wrong with using quotes, as you can see, the example in my answer has quotes too.

Comment: @Damianos_G I understand now, sorry :)

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this :

```js
const term = 'pasdefichier';

// Select all <p> elements and loop thought them
document.querySelectorAll('p').forEach(element => {
  // Check if the current element contains content of term variable
  if (element.innerText.includes(term)) {
    // Remove current element
    element.parentElement.removeChild(element);

  }

});
```

```html
<p class="downloadfileexintegradedindb" id="123456789" style="position: absolute; top: 36px; left: 123px;">pasdefichier</p>

<p class="downloadfileexintegradedindb" id="987654321" style="position: absolute; top: 36px; left: 123px;">stay</p>
```